# Quartz: Execute cron trigger, skip next execution

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am using quartz cron triggers in a java application. Is it possible to manually fire a cron trigger before its execution time, and skip the next execution as well?

**Example**: There is a cron trigger executed every day at 6am. But today I want to execute that trigger at 5am, but continue its execution tomorrow regularly at 6am (i.e. skipping today's execution).

Is that possible? I tried it with *triggerJob*, but that executes the cron job now AND fires it again at its original trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out-of-the-box by quartz, but you can implemented it with a couple of custom flags. In the class that manually triggers the job, you can put

```
JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
jobDataMap.put("manualExecution", true);

scheduledEventRuleJobScheduler.triggerJob(JobKey.jobKey("myJob"), jobDataMap);
```

And your job class can look like this

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class MyJob implements Job {

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobDataMap mergedJobDataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
    if (mergedJobDataMap.getBoolean("skipNextExecution")) {
      context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().remove("skipNextExecution");
      return;
    }
    if (mergedJobDataMap.getBoolean("manualExecution")) {
      context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().put("skipNextExecution", true);
    }
    doYourStuffHere();
  }
```

This will execute the job when is triggered manually and do nothing in the next (scheduled) job execution.

Comment: In the C# implementation you can register a ITriggerListener (IScheduler.ListenerManager) which can then veto the job execution. I guess it's the same for Java too?